# How to use SPSIteDataQuery to get all site collection list Having same column name?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, spsitedataquery

I am having one site collection that has
two sub sites `subSite1` and `subSite2`.

- `subSite1` Having List `EMP_info` with Column name `Title and Dept`.
- `subSite2` Having List `DEPT_info` with column name `Title and Dept_ID`.
- I want to show List `EMP_info` and `DEPT_info` on RootSite Visual Web Part.
- I implemented it By using `SPSiteDataQuery` writing two separate
  queries.
  Is it possible to have a single query? If yes, how to write Single query for that?

If there are 1000 sub site and 1000 list with same column name then how to get that 1000 list using single query.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the below code to get the required result:

```
SpDataqry.Lists="<Lists ServerTemplate=\"107\"/>";
SpDataqry.ViewFields="><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/><FieldRef Name=\"Priority\" Nullable=\"TRUE\" Type=\"Text\"/>";
SpDataqry.Query="<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/></orderBy> ";
SpDataqry.Webs="<Webs Scope="\SiteCollection\" />";
```

List template 107- is used for Task Lists. You can get List Template Id for other lists [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd958106(v=office.12).aspx)

Webs scope is set to Site collection level to get data from root site and sub sites below it.